# MPI C++ you want to treat each number with each number separately

Tags: c++, mpi

I have a problem with MPI C++.
I have array `int tab = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]`
I want to divide the tables due to the number of processes.
If I have two processes, divide

```
one process [1,2,3,4,5,6]
two process [7,8,9,10,11]
```

If i have three process divide:

```
one process [1,2,3,]
two process [4,5,6,7]
three process [8,9,10,11]
```

I do not know how to do it depending on the -n parameter.
How should I send these parts of the board to processes?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. I have read this question several times and cant figure out what you are asking. Maybe describe a bit more about what is the board and in which command is the -n parameter?

Comment: This is a textbook use case for `MPI_Scatterv()`

Comment: Please show first what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

If the current rank is `i` and the total number of ranks is `n`, then send to each rank from offset `static_cast<int>(size*std::static_cast<double>(i)/n)` to offset `static_cast<int>(size*std::static_cast<double>(i+1)/n)`.

This will split your data in a balanced way (better than `size/n` which will make the last rank have too much data).

Comment: I do not understand how to use it in the int array to send fragments in mpi c ++. np using MPI_Isend

Comment: Try starting with a synchronous send first, before doing async. You pass in the array at the given offset and the size you send is last offset - offset.